# List all external dependencies of a bazel target: name, version, license(s)

Tags: build, dependencies, bazel, envoyproxy, bazel-cpp

I have to list all the external dependencies of a bazel built project ([envoy](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy)), with their name, version and license(s).

I am looking for an output in any format that would list this information for each dependency embedded in the final binary (no tests requirements).

Looking at the [envoy](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy) repo, it seems all this information is available to the build system: [envoy/bazel/repository_locations.bzl](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/bazel/repository_locations.bzl)

I have a bazel build command used to produce an `envoy` static binary with many 'filters' and 'options':

```
bazel \
  build \
  --define google_grpc=disabled  \
  --@envoy//bazel:http3=False     \
  --@envoy//source/extensions/wasm_runtime/v8:enabled=false \
  [...]
  @envoy//source/exe:envoy-static
```

I have tried to play with the `query` command of `bazel` but I am not able to get what I want using it.

Is there a way to get the output I need ?

Comment: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_license

Comment: It seems interesting, do you know how to use it ? I cannot find any examples in the project.